# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - How to globalise system messages

Tags: translation, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to enable the system messages translation option but it is failing in my project.
In my main page js file i declare the following code globally

```
 WL.ClientMessages.loading = "Custom loading";
 function wlCommonInit(){
   var locale = WL.App.getDeviceLocale();
   var lang = WL.App.getDeviceLanguage();
   if (locale.indexOf("en")!=-1) languageChanged("english");
   if (locale.indexOf("fr")!=-1) languageChanged("french");
   if (locale.indexOf("ru")!=-1) languageChanged("russian");
   if (locale.indexOf("he")!=-1) languageChanged("hebrew")
}
```

This is hw to globalise the application strings but i have small doubts are 
      1. wt is system strings
      2. How to translate the it 
 i have gone through the docs but not clear to me pls help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet is not enough... it doesn't show exactly what you're doing in your app.

Please follow the [Enabling Translation training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/05_05_Enabling_translation.pdf) for the proper steps to make.
There is also [an example project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/EnablingTranslationProject.zip) that shows you how it is done. Compare it with yours.

---

Translation of native components (like the busy indicator) based on the system locale will be available in a future release.

In Worklight 5.0.6, the first busy indicator you see is controlled by Worklight and you cannot translate it. To overcome this, set connectOnStartup to 'false' and [create your own busy indicator](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/05_02_Common_UI_Controls.pdf). You can then translate its message as described in the module.

Please go over the [IBM Worklight Getting Started materials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) to familiarize yourself with the Worklight platform.

Comment: I went through it in example but i can't understand that hw to  translate system messages (translate native features like loading , alert.. )

Comment: I am nt asking about  application string

Comment: wil u pls tel me hw 2 create busy indicator by own .If we create busy indicator by using jquery i think it may nt look native feel and give some example for translating native features

Comment: jQuery Mobile has its own look & feel, that is correct. You should go over the IBM Worklight Getting Started materials. It is all covered there. Learn: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/05_02_Common_UI_Controls.pdf

Comment: I am using worklight provided busy indicator only . mine prblem is hw to translate it. pls tel the example

Comment: As they said in docs    WL.ClientMessages.requestTimeout = "Custom request timeout message";
WL.ClientMessages.invalidUsernamePassword = "Custom Username and password are not valid"; is declare in globally in mainpage js file

Comment: Please read my answer again - in Worklight 5.0.6 you cannot translate the Worklight-provided busy indicator.

Comment: For the rest of the issues, please edit your question with the contens of the HTML, JavaScript and messages.js files.

Comment: hw can we create own busy indicator

Comment: @venkataharika, I have already mentioned how. Go over the following training module. There is a section called "WL.BusyIndicator", follow the instructions: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/05_02_Common_UI_Controls.pdf

Comment: wil u pls give me an idea of translating system string using      WL.ClientMessages.loading = "Custom loading"; . I have gone through the docs its not clear to me . pls help me out