# Globalisation of system messages in worklight 5.0.6

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

wil u pls help out from globalisation of system messages using

```
WL.ClientMessages.loading = "Custom loading";
```

which is declared globally in common/js file.
I have gone to worklight docs but i couldnt understand hw to translate it to differnt languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WL.ClientMessages.loading = Messages.wrklight;
```

Will cause an error because the application messages in common/js/messages.js have not been loaded when this statement executes. To translate system messages I recommend using the device language and locale to select a language from a set of conditional statements. Here is a brief example:

```
if(WL.App.getDeviceLanguage() == 'en' && WL.App.getDeviceLocale() == 'en-US') {
    WL.ClientMessages.loading = 'Custom Loading Message';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A device's native system messages can be modified during application start-up by globally assigning a custom value to WL.ClientMessages.messageName before the wlCommonInit() function.

```
WL.ClientMessages.wlSettings = 'Custom Worklight Settings';
function wlCommonInit(){
```

As referenced in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17018898/2448991), the loading system message can only be modified when an application does not connect to the Worklight server on start-up.

```
var wlInitOptions = {
    connectOnStartup : false,
```

System messages are defined in .../wlclient/js/messages.js and can only be modified at start-up in the above fashion.  Application specific messages located in common/js/messages.js can be modified at run-time using JavaScript.  For examples and additional information please consult [IBM's Getting Started Page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development)

Comment: I followed wt u have said but small doubt in it. As u said that modifying system messages in start up only.so  wt would i write there instead of 'Custom Worklight Settings'? may i write 'message.wrklight' which declare in common/js/messages.js ? wil u pls tel me hw to internationalise